# Regular Expression that accepts a language L

Tags: regular-expressions

Given, $L=\{ x \in\{0,\,1\}^* | x=0^n1^m \text{ and }n+m\text{ is a multiple of }3\}$ give a regexp that accepts the language.

My thoughts are:   $(000)^*(\epsilon + 001 + 011)(111)^*$
Is this right?

Comment: My guess is $\{0^n1^m\mid n+m\text{ is a multiple of }3\}$. But the proposal doesn't work -- it admits strings such as `001001011011` that are not of that shape.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, edited the question. Sorry about that.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, true, got to rethink this one. Thx!

Comment: @HenningMakholm, edited the proposal. Does it look right now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Divide the word into blocks of $3$; the critical point is where the zeroes and ones meet. If $n=3k+1$, say, that block will be $011$. If $n$ is a multiple of $3$, on the other hand, there won’t be a mixed block: you’ll just have $(000)^*(111)^*$. Look at the possibilities for the mixed block, when it exists.

Comment: I've edited the proposed formula. Does that work?

Comment: @EggHead: No, because it still generates words that don’t have ones before zeroes, like $001001$. It also fails to generate the empty word, which is in $L$.

Comment: made changes. How about now?

Comment: @EggHead: Better, but you need to do more extensive testing. That outer star means that you can generate $001001$. There can be at most **one** mixed block, and it will be where the zeroes and ones meet.